# VSCode: Do we need to install extensions in order to use the Go to Definition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using VSCode 1.56.2 on `Windows`, without any extension installed. I'm using VSCode for `C++`. The problem is that the `go to definition, Go to declaration, Go To Type Definition, Go to References and Go to implementations` are disabled and I cannot use them.

I'm new VSCode. Do I need to install special extensions? If so, is it possible to do it offline too? Like download the package file and move it to the extensions folder where VSCode is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for each additional language you want to use in vscode, besides a few built-in ones like Javascript, Typescript, JSON and Markdown, you need to install an extension, which supports that language. Search for the particular language in the extension list in vscode or in the vscode marketplace.